# How do you use Snapshots feature in Adobe Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

At the moment I don't have any use at all for snapshots. Can't help thinking that I'm missing on something.

Seems like it might be a way to organize different processing versions of one photo, for example.

- It loses to Virtual Copy-based method in that you don't see all your versions at a glance in grid view.
- However, it wins in that it helps keep said grid view cleaner. (With virtual copies I have to use stacking to clean up the view, but stacking is already used for series of photos so it leads to a mess.)

I wonder how this feature fits in workflows of more experienced photographers.

Comment: I use it to keep both a b&w and a color version. I guess virtual copies would work for that too.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the reasons I decided to ask the question—to see if anyone had success managing different processing versions of same photo through Snapshots as opposed to virtual copies.

Comment: When I want to try different way of processing a photo I automatically make a virtual copy, and after a while my grid view becomes a mess. I try stacking them together, but I also stack sequences of photos shot continuously, and there's no way to, say, nest stacks…

Comment: Your question might seem less open-ended and vague if you rephrase it to something like "are there any advantages to using snapshots over virtual copies in LR?"

Comment: @MikeW “Are there any advantages to using snapshots over virtual copies for managing different processing versions in LR?” is one way to ask this, but I think it's too subjective (advantages seen by each photographer may vary, depend on their workflow and habits).

Comment: So I decided to ask simply: how the feature fits in your workflow?

Answer (score 5):

It's more of a "bulk undo" than anything else; an easy way to revert to a previous point in processing if you've found that something you're trying to do isn't working out well. It's very much like using history, except that you get to define your landmarks and don't have to remember what that last processing step before everything started going wrong was. And you have to option to take both paths when you come to a fork in the road, so to speak. It's not intended to be a permanent record of processing versions, just a way to facilitate and encourage experimentation during a single session with a picture.

Comment: To add to that I use a plug-in that creates a shapshot whenever I export.  That way if I do more work on an image I can easily bet back to the version that I shared with someone.

Comment: @IanLelsie I think in LR 5 it's enabled by default, at least when using Publish Services I see corresponding records (with timestamps) appearing in photo's history.

Comment: Good to know @AntonStrogonoff.  I am still running Vista so only have LR4 at the moment.